# How to create a shopping cart(Ecommerce site) using NetSuite

Tags: netsuite

I am new to NetSuite. I don't know anything about the NetSuite. I want to create a new Shoppping cart(Ecommerce site) in the NetSuite. I am not able to find the steps so that I can create a new shopping cart using the NetSuite.

Please anybody provide me the full information of the NetSuite so that I can start the work on the E-commerce site.

Answer (score 0):

with such a generic question I can only give a generic answer, which is to start at the start and learn about the system you are about to work with.
https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl
If you have specific questions or issues, folks here can be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

- First, the netsuite account must have the ecommerce module.
- Understanding of item types in Netsuite (items are integrated in ecommerce).
- Netsuite website template, they are not the best in terms of UI design but you can always do something about it using css.
- Of course the help guide and Netsuite usergroup is one of the best resources out there.